# How to know the highcharts version used in angular2-highcharts

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am trying to use time feature of highcharts but it is not supported in my application as I am using angular2-highcarts of version 0.5.5 .I want to know what is the high charts version used in angular2-highcharts , is there any way to upgrade highcharts version of angular2-highcharts

Comment: Have a look on this [https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts)

Comment: Have you considered using the official Highcharts wrapper for Angular - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular ? It's maintained by Highcharts developers and has full Highcharts support, so latest Highcharts version is supported there.

Answer (score 0):

angular2-highcarts is not supported anymore, its latest version has been **0.5.5** for a long time now. you can see the exact highcharts version it's using in your package-lock.json file.

If you still decide to use this library, I would suggest to not update highcharts over version **6.1.0**. I did an update to **7.2.0** (currently latest) and the charts did not render properly anymore. As I didn't want to rewrite some logic and move to another library, then I just downgraded and it works perfectly again with **Angular 8.2**